# Hyper-V machines refusing to start after BIOS upgrade

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 Server with Hyper-V installed, and a couple of VMs.

All was working properly until I tried upgrading BIOS. All of a sudden I get permission denied when attempting to start any VM, saying 'general access denied error' on the vhd file.

[image: Error message]

I have attempted the fix at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2249906 and http://techblog.mirabito.net.au/?p=275 - both with the same result.

Also SYSTEM, and NETWORK SERVICE accounts have full access.

How can I fix this issue?

***Edit:** Even creating a new virtual machine + disk is giving this error, but I can inspect an existing disk, and even expand it without problems. Also cdrom device is giving the same error. If I remove all harddrives and cdrom devices from settings, I may power on the VM without any 'General access denied error'.

***Edit2:** I attempted to completely remove Hyper-V and reinnstall it again - same result.

Comment: "If I remove all harddrives and cdrom devices from settings, it starts."  this doesn't make sense what starts?

Comment: The VM can be powered on (naturally it can't load any OS tho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the user NETWORK SERVICE to the group Administrators solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd error to get in response to a BIOS upgrade.  If you're certain those files are in those locations and the access control lists haven't been changed, I'd look at the BIOS itself.  A BIOS upgrade can frequently reset the BIOS to its factory default settings.  Perhaps virtualization itself is turned off.

Comment: Virtualization bits were turned on again after bios reset, and the files are there